# getting image size in google chrome is undefined

Tags: jquery, html, google-chrome, getimagesize

I have several image tags and div in my html as below.

My requirment is to calculate the height * width of each image and do the following if the height * width is <5000.
    1) Remove the correspponding div
    2) remove the class 'captify' of correcsponding image

For this I have tried the below script for handling google chrome since I have managed to work for IE and firefox using some other method.

```
$('img[class = "captify"]').each(function(){

var $that = $(this),
picRealWidth = 0,
picRealHeight = 0,
imgSize = 0,
dvHiResCaption = null,
src = $that.attr( 'src' ),
rel = $that.attr( 'rel' );

// creating a clone in memory
$('<img/>').attr('src', src)
.load(function(){
picRealWidth = parseInt( this.width );
picRealHeight = parseInt( this.height );
}, function(){
// called once the load is complete
imgSize = picRealWidth * picRealHeight;

if( imgSize < 5000 ){
dvHiResCaption = '#' + rel;
$(dvHiResCaption).remove();
$that.removeClass( 'captify' );
}
});
});
```

Can any one help me on this please. Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
$('img.captify').each(function(i,img){
    img.onload = function() {
        if ((this.width * this.height) < 5000) {
            $('#' + $(this).attr('rel')).remove();
            $(this).removeClass('captify');
        }
    }
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no such methods [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5DjLw/). this inside load function is not jQuery object but this is JavaScript HTMLElement.
Use:

```
.....
picRealWidth = $(this).width( ); // return integer value
picRealHeight =  $(this)..height( );  // return integer value
.....
```

Answer (score 0):

use $(this).width, $(this).height

```
$('<img/>').attr('src', src)
.load(function(){
picRealWidth =$(this).width();
picRealHeight = $(this).height();
.......
```